# Cannot import processing.serial.* Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm trying to import processing.serial.* in Eclipse but It says the library is not found, it works fine in processing's ide, is there anything I'm not noticing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the `jar` which has the `package` `processing.serial.*` to `eclipse buildpath`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to which `jar` this package is located in? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The library is located at: pathToProcessing\modes\java\libraries\serial

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers I'd like to recommend the [Proclipsing Processing eclipse plugin](https://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/wiki/GettingStarted).

It easily allows you to create and export Processing Java projects
and use existing libraries (like processing-serial)

[image: Proclipsing serial]

Also, there's a video guide available [here](https://vimeo.com/19076476)